# Configurable Simulink inside library

Tags: simulink

I need to create a simulink library block that has a configurable subsystem inside.

One of my requirements is that the end user can change the configurable subsystem (inside the library) block choice as a mask parameter of the library without breaking the link.

Also, since this block will be used 100000x times, I cannot use the initialization panel of mask editor due to performance issues when loading the model.

Each library instance should use a different block choice...

Is it possible to implement? How?

Answer (score 1):

I figure it out..

You need to set the 'Allow library block to modify its contents' checkbox inside Mask Editor/Initialization pane